# YAML python parser

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml

I have a YAML file of the following format:

```
innings:
      - 1st innings:
          team: England
          deliveries:
            - 0.1:
                batsman: ME Trescothick
                bowler: Shoaib Akhtar
                extras:
                  wides: 1
                non_striker: AJ Strauss
                runs:
                  batsman: 0
                  extras: 1
                  total: 1
            - 0.2:
                batsman: ME Trescothick
                bowler: Shoaib Akhtar
                non_striker: AJ Strauss
                runs:
                  batsman: 0
                  extras: 0
                  total: 0
      - 2nd innings:
          team: Pakistan
          deliveries:
            - 0.1:
                batsman: Shoaib Malik
                bowler: D Gough
                non_striker: Mohammad Hafeez
                runs:
                  batsman: 2
                  extras: 0
                  total: 2
            - 0.2:
                batsman: Shoaib Malik
                bowler: D Gough
                extras:
                  wides: 5
                non_striker: Mohammad Hafeez
                runs:
                  batsman: 0
                  extras: 5
                  total: 5
```

I am using the following code to access yaml data:

```
with open(fpath, 'r') as stream:
    datamap = yaml.safe_load(stream)
x = bunchify(datamap)
print x.innings[0]
```

The print statements gives me the following result:

```
- 1st innings:
          team: England
          deliveries:
            - 0.1:
                batsman: ME Trescothick
                bowler: Shoaib Akhtar
                extras:
                  wides: 1
                non_striker: AJ Strauss
                runs:
                  batsman: 0
                  extras: 1
                  total: 1
            - 0.2:
                batsman: ME Trescothick
                bowler: Shoaib Akhtar
                non_striker: AJ Strauss
                runs:
                  batsman: 0
                  extras: 0
                  total: 0
```

But when I try to access the 1st innings using the statement:

```
print x.innings[0].1st innings
```

It throws an error. I even tried by assigning the string "1st innings" to a variable and use it. But it throws an error:

```
inn = "1st innings"
print x.innings[0].inn
```

I need to get the total number of runs. For which I need to add the total of every ball in the list `[0.1, 0.2,...]`.

Comment: You can't do `x.innings[0].1st innings`... It breaks at the space, so you are doing `x.innings[0].1st` which also isn't correct. Maybe you meant something like `x.innings[0]['1st innings']`?

Comment: 1. `1st innings` isn't a valid [identifier name](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers). 2. `x.innings[0].inn` is looking for an attribute literally named `inn`, it doesn't care what you've assigned to the variable `inn`. You either need `getattr` or key notation, as @cricket_007 shows.

Comment: @cricket_007 that worked. But when I try to access the total of each ball using print x.innings[0]['1st innings'].deliveries[2].runs it throws error. What mistake am I doing here. Can you please tell a way to count the total runs for each inning?

Comment: You need to stop using dot notation like you have an object. Keep using key-notation.

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried this print x.innings[0]['1st innings']['deliveries'] it prints all the data i.e., each ball information. But then I don't understand how to access the data inside "deliveries".

Comment: `['deliveries'][0]` perhaps? Just keep printing each step... don't go too far, if you get an error, just go back a step

Comment: @cricket_007 I already tried that. Prints the information of first ball. But if I do x.innings[0]['1st innings']['deliveries'][0]['runs'] it says  "KeyError: 'runs'"

Comment: What about `['deliveries'][0]['0.1']['runs']`

Comment: @cricket_007 still gives KeyError.

Comment: `>>> x['innings'][0]['1st innings']['deliveries'][0][0.1]['runs']` returns
`{'batsman': 0, 'extras': 1, 'total': 1}` dictionary keys can be any hashable object even a float or an integer, so you want to use `0.1` the number not a string.

Comment: Although note that using a float as a key is probably a bad idea, as comparisons don't always work out how you think they should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Converting to Python lists & dictionaries](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/), you get this structure, call it `x`.

Some values from the comments are

- `x.innings` or `x['innings']` - Returns a list of Python dictionaries keyed by `"1st innings"` and `"2nd innings"`
- `x.innings[0]` - Returns the first dictionary from the above list
- `x.innings[0]['1st innings']` - Returns the dictionary value of the `"1st innings"` key in the first item in the `innings` list.
- `x.innings[0]['1st innings']['deliveries']` - Returns a list of Python dictionaries keyed by `0.1` and `0.2`.
- `x.innings[0]['1st innings']['deliveries'][0]` - Returns the first dictionary from the above list
- `x.innings[0]['1st innings']['deliveries'][0][0.1]` - Returns the JSON Object value of the `0.1` key in the first item in the `deliveries` list.
- `x.innings[0]['1st innings']['deliveries'][0][0.1]['runs']` - Returns the dictionary of the `'runs'`

Data:

```
{
  "innings": [
    {
      "1st innings": {
        "deliveries": [
          {
            0.1: {
              "batsman": "ME Trescothick", 
              "bowler": "Shoaib Akhtar", 
              "runs": {
                "batsman": 0, 
                "total": 1, 
                "extras": 1
              }, 
              "extras": {
                "wides": 1
              }, 
              "non_striker": "AJ Strauss"
            }
          }, 
          {
            0.2: {
              "batsman": "ME Trescothick", 
              "bowler": "Shoaib Akhtar", 
              "runs": {
                "batsman": 0, 
                "total": 0, 
                "extras": 0
              }, 
              "non_striker": "AJ Strauss"
            }
          }
        ], 
        "team": "England"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "2nd innings": { ... }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I used the tool in the link on the "Converting to JSON" text

Comment: When you load a YAML string using [`yaml.load`](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#LoadingYAML) it returns a python object that corresponds to the YAML object, so in this case dictionaries and lists.

Comment: @MarkMikofski Sure, but the JSON syntax is more or less directly equivalent to Python lists and dictionaries

Comment: True except for keys. According to the [JSON.org ECMA standard](http://json.org/), JSON keys must be strings so [`json.dumps(x)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) , where x is the loaded YAML string, converted the keys that were floats to strings. =\_o_/=

Comment: @MarkMikofski All good points. Have edited answer to reflect Python objects

Answer (score 1):

[@laxmi23](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5965943/laxmi23) welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the section on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask questions that get more answers and more votes. You might also enjoy reading [How to create a mimimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Your question was *probably* voted down because it *appears* that you may not have done sufficient research before posting. In particular the section of the [YAML Tutorial on `load`](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#LoadingYAML) says it returns a Python object. Searching the [Python Tutorial on Data Types](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) you can see how to index various Python objects such as [Lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) and [Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) which is what you need here:

```
>>> import yaml  # use the PyYAML package to load your YAML string
>>> yaml.load("""
innings:
- 1st innings:
    deliveries:
    - 0.1:
        batsman: ME Trescothick
        bowler: Shoaib Akhtar
        extras: {wides: 1}
        non_striker: AJ Strauss
        runs: {batsman: 0, extras: 1, total: 1}
    - 0.2:
        batsman: ME Trescothick
        bowler: Shoaib Akhtar
        non_striker: AJ Strauss
        runs: {batsman: 0, extras: 0, total: 0}
    team: England
- 2nd innings:
    deliveries:
    - 0.1:
        batsman: Shoaib Malik
        bowler: D Gough
        non_striker: Mohammad Hafeez
        runs: {batsman: 2, extras: 0, total: 2}
    - 0.2:
        batsman: Shoaib Malik
        bowler: D Gough
        extras: {wides: 5}
        non_striker: Mohammad Hafeez
        runs: {batsman: 0, extras: 5, total: 5}
    team: Pakistan
""")

{'innings': [{'1st innings': {'deliveries': [{0.1: {'batsman': 'ME Trescothick',
       'bowler': 'Shoaib Akhtar',
       'extras': {'wides': 1},
       'non_striker': 'AJ Strauss',
       'runs': {'batsman': 0, 'extras': 1, 'total': 1}}},
     {0.2: {'batsman': 'ME Trescothick',
       'bowler': 'Shoaib Akhtar',
       'non_striker': 'AJ Strauss',
       'runs': {'batsman': 0, 'extras': 0, 'total': 0}}}],
    'team': 'England'}},
  {'2nd innings': {'deliveries': [{0.1: {'batsman': 'Shoaib Malik',
       'bowler': 'D Gough',
       'non_striker': 'Mohammad Hafeez',
       'runs': {'batsman': 2, 'extras': 0, 'total': 2}}},
     {0.2: {'batsman': 'Shoaib Malik',
       'bowler': 'D Gough',
       'extras': {'wides': 5},
       'non_striker': 'Mohammad Hafeez',
       'runs': {'batsman': 0, 'extras': 5, 'total': 5}}}],
    'team': 'Pakistan'}}]}
```

Looking at the first line of the response `{'innings': [{'1st innings': ...` you can see the outer object is a dictionary, which contains a list of dictionaries. Therefore access the Python Object as the Python Data Types Tutorial demonstrate using brackets.

```
>>> y['innings'][0]['1st innings']  # index into the returned Python object

{'deliveries': [{0.1: {'batsman': 'ME Trescothick',
    'bowler': 'Shoaib Akhtar',
    'extras': {'wides': 1},
    'non_striker': 'AJ Strauss',
    'runs': {'batsman': 0, 'extras': 1, 'total': 1}}},
  {0.2: {'batsman': 'ME Trescothick',
    'bowler': 'Shoaib Akhtar',
    'non_striker': 'AJ Strauss',
    'runs': {'batsman': 0, 'extras': 0, 'total': 0}}}],
 'team': 'England'}
```

As I said in the comment above, Python dictionary keys can be any hashable, even a float. So in order to find the `runs` use `0.1` as a number not a string. Assume we captured the `load` response as `x`.

```
>>> x['innings'][0]['1st innings']['deliveries'][0][0.1]['runs']
{'batsman': 0, 'extras': 1, 'total': 1}
```